# Cloud Services - Two web roles sharing file system

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a very special requirement which is:

Two web roles accessing a local shared file location.

I am aware of the "Local Storage" role settings, but those are only accessible within each role scope.

Does anyone know another option to accomplish this?

------- EDIT --------

As suggested I will explain more clearly what I'm trying to achieve here.

I'm implementing [Only Office](http://www.onlyoffice.com) which is a web editor for office files. Their product requires to have a file saved on the file system to be opened on the editor.

I don't want to mix their ASP.NET MVC open source project with my code, so that's why I want to deploy their website as a separate webrole.

-------- END EDIT ------------

Thanks

Comment: Isn't blob storage a good solution for this?

Comment: I also thought about that, but since I already have the file locally I would like to avoid sending it to the cloud and getting it back.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to give further detail on what you are trying to share. How big is/are the file/s? How many? Read only or read/write? How frequent? The problem with using local storage is that it isn't durable in the event of a failure/scale/update etc. You say avoiding sending to the cloud and back but if the blob storage/vhd, cache, or whatever is in the same datacentre as the web roles is that too much of a performance hit? If you could provide more background I think people would be better able to provide suggestions.

Comment: Have you looked at Azure File Service? You can essentially mount a file service share as a network drive in both VMs and share the files that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you state that (my emphasis):

> I'm implementing Only Office which is a web editor for office files. **Their product requires to have a file saved on the file system to be opened on the editor.**

If *Only Office's* requirement is to have **temporary** file storage that is used while the document is being edited, you may be able to get away with this in a Cloud Service Web Role. This is assuming that your users wouldn't be too angry if the temp. working document was 'lost' during a role re-start.

Web (and Worker) Roles are non-durable and the Azure Service Fabric might bounce them if they need to patch the underlying host or they might just crash due to a fault (which is usually why you deploy them in pairs - fault-tolerance etc.) If you save something to the file system on a Web Role, you are not guaranteed that it will be there if the role is bounced.

If however you need durability, you will need to implement something based around [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) and possibly something based on [Blob Leases](http://justazure.com/azure-blob-storage-part-8-blob-leases/). However I imagine that *Only Office* doesn't have an implementation for Azure....

Failing that, you could try running on [Azure Web App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/web/), however I imagine you would have the same issue re. backing storage and would need to implement something on Blob Storage.

So, finally, if you want complete control and something akin to running on-premise, take a look at using an IaaS Virtual Machine where you have all of the file system to play-with as you please.

**==UPDATE==**

Taking a look at the Only Office website, there is a SaaS offering [Only Office SaaS Hosting](http://www.onlyoffice.com/saas.aspx) which is probably cheaper to run for a year than the time taken for me to write this answer!

Failing that, if you look at the requirements for [Only Office Document Server](http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/windows/document/install-office-apps.aspx) there is **no way** you're going to run that on a Web Role. Go Azure IaaS VM's.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 2 options here, both mentioned in the comments. You can use BLOB storage, or you can use an SMB share using Azure Files, which I believe is in preview still. We have used Azure files to mount an SMB share on several linux boxes. One thing we have noticed is that it is not particularly fast. It is also built on top of blob storage. Here is a link to Azure Files https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/.

If you choose to use blob storage and you will need to consider concurrency.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Azure File Services, you could have a share like URI to be used.

take a look at this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/